# G Suite Add-on refusing to connect to drive? How to solve "drive.google.com refused to connect" error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon, end-user

I am trying to use a G Suite Add-on called YAMM that I regularly use. Recently, I have been encountering an error "drive.google.com refused to connect" often. When I contacted the developer, they say it is Google's problem. How do I get it fixed?